# Nested Accounts in Solana Anchor (Maybe a custom data types in account)

Tags: rust, blockchain, solana, anchor-solana

I would like to achieve a linked list type data structure in my anchor program. However I can't bring myself to understand how I can use nested account. Following is the code I am using:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Create<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 8 + 32 + 8 + 8 + 32 )]
    pub endpoint: Account<'info, Endpoint>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Update<'info> {
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut, has_one = authority)]
    pub endpoint: Account<'info, Endpoint>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Endpoint {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub data: u64,
    pub len: u64,
    pub next: Endpoint
}

impl Endpoint {
    pub fn push(&mut self, data:u64){
        if self.len  == 0 {
            self.data = data;
        } else {
            // Recursion to push data into the next node
        }
        self.len += 1;
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is that an account named Endpoint has a parameter named 'next' which stores another Endpoint account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

You can't query an account in the on-chain. You can only read an account only if you put the account inside your instruction. In Anchor, the account you can interact with is the Account inside the `Context`.

Another way, you can allocate a data account that stores an array of struct. So you can read all those structs inside the array. *Don't forget that the data account size can't be adjusted, so make sure you allocate it as much as you need.*